# mysql query - edit extra fields

Tags: php, mysql

I have 3 TABLES products, products_extra_fields, products_to_products_extra_fields

products TABLE

```
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| products_id | categories_id| products_name |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
| 1           | 1            | product 1     |
| 2           | 1            | product 2     |
+-------------+--------------+---------------+
```

products_extra_fields TABLE

```
+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| products_extra_fields_id | products_extra_fields_name| 
+--------------------------+---------------------------+
| 1                        | sugar                     |
| 2                        | cocoa                     |
| 3                        | butter                    |
| 4                        | milk                      |
+--------------------------+---------------------------+
```

products_to_products_extra_fields TABLE

```
+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
| products_id | products_extra_fields_id  | products_extra_fields_value |
+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
| 1           | 1                         | 20%                         |
| 1           | 2                         | 45%                         |
| 1           | 3                         | 27%                         |
| 2           | 1                         | 12%                         |
+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------------------+
```

I wanna edit **product 1** I use this query:

```
SELECT 
products_name, 
products_extra_fields_name, 
products_extra_fields_value FROM products, products_extra_fields, products_to_products_extra_fields 
WHERE products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id = products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id AND 
products_to_products_extra_fields.products_id=1 
GROUP BY products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id;

+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| products_name | products_extra_fields_name| products_extra_fields_value|
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| product 1     | sugar                     | 20%                        |
| product 1     | cocoa                     | 45%                        |
| product 1     | butter                    | 27%                        |
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

But I wanna see

products_extra_fields_name (milk) with no value

```
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| products_name | products_extra_fields_name| products_extra_fields_value|
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| product 1     | sugar                     | 20%                        |
| product 1     | cocoa                     | 45%                        |
| product 1     | butter                    | 27%                        |
| product 1     | milk                      |                            |
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

and for product 2 cocoa, butter, milk with no value only sugar 12%

What can I do to get the results I want.

look at my php script (products_edit2.php?id=1 or 2 )

```
<?php  
require ('mysql/mysql_connect.php'); // Connect to the database.
        if (is_numeric ($_GET['id']) ) {
    $query = "SELECT 
products_name, products_extra_fields_name, products_extra_fields_value FROM 
products, products_extra_fields, products_to_products_extra_fields WHERE 
products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id = products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id AND 
products_to_products_extra_fields.products_id = {$_GET['id']} 
GROUP BY  products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id";

if ($result = mysql_query ($query)) {

$query2 = "SELECT products_name FROM products WHERE products_id={$_GET['id']}";
if ($result2 = mysql_query ($query2)) {
$row2 = mysql_fetch_array ($result2);
$products_name = $row2['products_name'];
?>

<form action='products_edit.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
<table width="50%" border="0" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
<tr>
<td width="20%" align="right">PRODUCTS NAME:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="products_name" size="80" value="<?php echo $products_name; ?>" /></td>
</tr>
<?php 
}
/***** ***** *****/

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result)) {
$products_extra_fields_name = $row['products_extra_fields_name'];
$products_extra_fields_value = $row['products_extra_fields_value'];
$products_extra_fields_id = $row['products_extra_fields_id'];
?>
<tr>
<td width="20%" align="right"><?php echo $products_extra_fields_id .'-'. $products_extra_fields_name; ?></td>
<td><input type="text" name="categories_name" size="80" value="<?php echo $products_extra_fields_value; ?>" /></td>
</tr>

<?php }

/***** ***** END *****/
?>
<input type="hidden" name="categories_id" size="10" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>" />

<tr>
<td width="100%" colspan="2" align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="SAVE"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

<?php
} else { // Couldn't get the information.
print "<p>Could retrieve the entry because: <b>" . mysql_error() . "</b><br/><br/>. The query was $query.</p>";
}
}else{ // No ID set.
print '<p><b>You must have made a mistake in using this page.</b></p>';
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I wanna see all 4 products_extra_fields_name and 4 input box (product 1 have 3 value 1 null, product 2 have 1 value 3 null)

Comment: You should *not* use `$_GET['id']` directly in your query because of SQL injections.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use a comma separated list in FROM, MySQL uses an Inner Join.  To get what you want, you need to use a Left Join.

```
SELECT 
products_name, 
products_extra_fields_name, 
products_extra_fields_value
FROM products, products_extra_fields
LEFT JOIN products_to_products_extra_fields
ON products_to_products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id = products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id
AND products_to_products_extra_fields.products_id=1 
GROUP BY products_extra_fields.products_extra_fields_id;
```

This should produce:

```
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| products_name | products_extra_fields_name| products_extra_fields_value|
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
| product 1     | sugar                     | 20%                        |
| product 1     | cocoa                     | 45%                        |
| product 1     | butter                    | 27%                        |
| product 1     | milk                      | NULL                       |
+---------------+---------------------------+----------------------------+
```

Comment: thx but your answer is not full, I edit my question see my php script

Comment: sorry for my previous comment YOUR ANSWER IS FULL

Comment: @chris: Glad I could help :-D